How to fix Foundry `script failed: vm.envUint: environment variable not found` error?
I'm trying to reference my private key inside a Foundry deploy script from my .env file, however, the script suddenly does not recognize my variable despite it working perfectly previously.
contract DiamondCutFacetDeployScript is Script {
    DiamondCutFacet public diamondCutFacet;

    function run() public returns (address) {
        vm.startBroadcast(vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY"));
        diamondCutFacet = new DiamondCutFacet();
        vm.stopBroadcast();
        return address(diamondCutFacet);
    }
}

Error:
script failed: vm.envUint: environment variable "PRIVATE_KEY" not found

I am certain the spelling is identical so that can't be the issue. I've also tried running forge clean and npx hardhat clean to no avail.

I had the same issue, in the end was just the // in front of the group of the variables. If you want to add any comment in this .env file just use # Also to verify is working use source .env to see if it can read the variables etc

Strangely enough, the solution for me was to put a space in between the variable name and the = inside of the .env file. Once I had put a space in between, the deploy script worked perfectly:
PRIVATE_KEY = 0xabc...abc

Afterward, I tested removing the spaces and running the deploy script and it seems to work either way again, even after running forge clean:
PRIVATE_KEY=0xabc...abc

